# Why can't I copy public variable from one Form to another?

Tags: c#

(Hopefully this is not a duplicate)

I have two forms (FormA, FormB) in the same project. I intialize those form with static properties in a dedicated separate class. There is one public variable in FormA that recieves a textbox string. I want to access that variable is from FormB to copy its content to a formB textbox. But it failed.

```
class utilities
{
   public static FormA formA = new FormA();
   public static FormB formB = new FormB();
}
```

**Form A**

```
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    //Note : This form is the first that is opened when the program starts
    public string textA;
    private void formA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*formATextBox.Text recieves its value here using C# random number
            generation function*/

            textA = formATextBox.Text 

            /* MessageBox.Show(textA) here confirms that 
              the text has been copied in the variable */
        }
}
```

**Form B**

```
public partial class formB : Form
{
    //This form is opened onclick of a button on formA

    private void formB_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formBTextBox.Text = Utilities.formA.textA;  
            //This line fails i.e. it returns blank in formBTextBox.Text
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do you open `FormA`?

Comment: The value is only set on `formA_Load `. Are you sure that the form has loaded by the time that you call it?

Comment: Also, how does `formATextBox.Text` gets its value?

Comment: Because `formA_Load()` is called when user do `formA.Show() or formA.ShowDialog()`. If you show FormA by `Application.Run(/*Form A*/)`, it can not set value for Utilities.formA.textA. They are two instances of FormA

Comment: @PatrickHofman Dont worry about that. FormA is Openned when the whole program starts. And then FormB is oppend onclick of a button on FormA....`formATextBox.Text` also gets its value on load of FormA. As I said, I used `MessageBox.show(formATextBox.Text)` and `MessageBox.show(textA)` to ensure everything was set.  I update my question

Comment: I am not worrying, you are the one wanting this to be fixed, and you are not helping us finding the problem. So why don't you post the code and let us decide if that is okay or not.

Comment: Utilites class doesnt appear to be static itself, so, in your formB you dont appear to have mentioned then passing utilities to the forms.

Comment: If you do not pass formA as argument to formB, there is no way you can access the content of formA

Comment: @GSP You get my point. Actually, I only care about `static FormB formB .....` here. When I click on button on FormA, I call `Utilities.formB.show()`

Comment: @BugFinder please see my above comment to GSP

Comment: @snorlax I see that comment, but your code doesnt show utilities as static, so there could be more than one instance of utilities...

Comment: @GSP YES !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You are awesome GSP. Actually  I needed to call `Application.Run` with `Utilities.formA`.... I did it and it worked. Only problem is `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` in main program raised an exception but I commented it so it's not considered. Is it ok if I leave it commented ?

Comment: @BugFinder  Ok. PLease see my new above comment. Actually `Utilities` is just here so I can use its static element without having to create an `Utilities` object

Comment: @snorlax To pass a variable from FormA to FormB, you needn't create `utilities` class. First, you create two forms A and B normally. Second, you create another constructor of B `public FormB(string strTextFromFormA)`. Third, you create an object of FormB `FormB frmB = new FormB(formATextBox.Text)` in `click event` of FormA. Finally, you show FormB `frmB.Show()`

Comment: @snorlax Another if you still want to use `utilities` class. You should add `Utilities.formA.textA = formATextBox.Text` in `formA_Load()`. But it is bad.

Comment: @snorlax Another you should make `public static string textA;` and get its value in FormB by `FormA.textA` directly. P/s: This way does not use `utilities` too.

Comment: @GSP Thanks. Actually I need (I was taught) to use `utilities` as I'll need to go back and forth between several forms (A, B, C, etc....). So using `utilities` and its static objects allow me to create only one objects (or even recreate that one object) for the whole time the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

A call to `new FormA();` does NOT automatically trigger the Form_Load event. You need to do `formA.Show()` or something similar to commence its Init and Load cycle.

**And related, a piece of advice:**

If you need to pass values from one Form to another, then using a global storage location (e.g. `public static class MyData`, with static properties as needed) can be a much better solution.
Reason: when a Form is closed all its data is purged, but the static class `MyData` stays in memory for the duration of the application, so you can access it all the time, and from anywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you. I'll put the formA public variable in my `Utilities` class. And you are right. It was the default `Application.Run` that was opening my form. S there where to instances of the form and I was accessing the wrong one. I corrected it by using `Application.Run(Utilities.formA)`

Answer (score 0):

So much negative comments on my question. People downvote instead of trying to undertand the issue...

Thanks to GSP, Peter B and Patrick Hoffman, I realised I was not accessing the correct form.

`Application.Run(Utilities.formA)` should be used instead of the default `Application.Run(new formA())`